# Implementar funções em aplicação web2py usando jQuery

Tags: jquery, web2py

Olá. Não sei se é o termo correto, mas eu tenho uma aplicação feita usando web2py como framework. Eu sei absolutamente nada de jQuery mas a página inicial do site que eu criei está demorando muito pra carregar e eu queria tentar usar aquela função infinite scroll e todo texto que eu vejo por aí sobre isso usa jQuery. Então estou disposto a aprender o básico afim de entender os snippets que tornam possível essa função.

Gostaria de saber se eu teria que aprender apenas jQuery ou é necessário aprender alguma outra linguagem para implementar o infinite scroll na aplicação — pergunto isso porque sempre que vejo algo sobre jQuery, em algum momento Ajax aparece junto — e se é tranquilo e intuitivo, uma vez aprendido o necessário, deixar tudo funcionando em uma aplicação já existente.

Muitíssimo obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta deve vir de você mesmo. E a pergunta que se deve fazer é:

> **quero compreender o código que corre na minha página?**

- Sim!

Entäo aprender e usar uma biblioteca como jQuery ou MooTools é uma boa ideia pois poupa muito código. Acelera a escrita de um código que faz essa funcionalidade.

- Näo!

Pague a alguém que faça isso por sí.

---

Comment: No caso eu quero sim, mas o que eu queria saber inicialmente é se web2py e jquery é tranquilo e se eu teria que aprender jquery apenas ou jquery mais ajax, entende? Você tem alguma ideia em relação a isso?

Comment: @duarthiago depende muito do que quer e você sabe muito pouco para esta pergunta fazer sentido. Não que o queira desencorajar a perguntar. Perguntar é bom e foi assim que eu aprendi, mas neste caso não dá para responder simples. Uma coisa é certa, a funcionalidade que quer não tem nada a ver com ajax. E já agora você podia até fazer isso com CSS transitions e uma linha de javascript simples (nada de jQuery) que dispara o scroll e o CSS faz o resto...

Comment: Entendo. Mas achei interessante essa possível alternativa que você citou. Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre isso. Muito obrigado.